# appending to a string does not change string value

Tags: c++, c++11, stat

I'm trying to learn c++ for a project and I'm having a bit of a problem with string concatenation.
My application consists of the application itself and a statically linked library project.
In the library I've defined a type representing a path on the file system, acting as a wrapper around a std::string path literal.
I've defined a function to concatenate the parent folder's path with the (user supplied) name of the file/folder itself, adding in path separators as needed.
The function code looks like this:

```
std::string normalize(std::string parentPath, const std::string& name) {
    if (name.empty()) {
        return parentPath;
    } else {
        parentPath.reserve(parentPath.length()+name.length()+1);
        if (*name.begin() != Path::SEGMENT_SEPARATOR) {
            parentPath.append(1,Path::SEGMENT_SEPARATOR);
        }
        if(*name.rbegin() != Path::SEGMENT_SEPARATOR){
            parentPath.append(name);
        }else{
            parentPath.append(name.begin(), --name.end());
        }
        return parentPath;
    }
}
```

(Path::SEGMENT_SEPARATOR is a const char '/')

The problem is this: every call to string::append does not seem to do anything.
I debugged the function with gdb and the content of parentPath does not change.
I checked the user input, looking for '/0' or other invalid characters in the input ("name"), but did not find anything wrong with it.

When I moved the exact same function to the application project (out of the library project), it did work as expected (with the same input).

Both projects are compiled using the same toolset (GCC 4.8.1 and are using the C++11 dialect) and the same compiler parameters (all warnings on, no warnings received in code).
Is there anything in my code which could break string::append in this fashion ?

**EDIT:** the function is called from:

```
Path::Path(const Path& parent, const std::string& name) : path_(normalize(parent.path_, name)) { }
Path::Path(const Path& parent, const char* name) : Path(parent, std::string(name)) {}
```

Which in turn is called from(header file):

```
extern const IO::Path CONFIG_PATH;
extern const IO::Path LANGUAGES_PATH;
```

With definition in cpp file:

```
const IO::Path Game::CONFIG_PATH{"conf"};
const IO::Path Game::LOG_PATH{CONFIG_PATH,"log"};
```

Inspection of the LOG_PATH object shows its 'path_' member value as just "conf" instead of "conf/log" as expected.
Can I be sure CONFIG_PATH is initialized before LOG_PATH, can this be the problem?

EDIT:
I read up the standard and it seems you can't rely on any initialization order for globals.
This means the declarations of CONFIG_PATH and LOG_PATH are obviously errors and I should probably wrap them into a function call like this:

```
const IO::Path &getConfigPath(){
  static IO::Path config{"conf"};
  return config;
};
```

Can this be why the string appending fails ?

Comment: Why you don't use `+` to concat strings? And you don't have to reserve before append.

Comment: Ok. I'm genuinely curious. Does `push_back()` exhibit the same issue for single chars, or does *nothing* seem to modify `parentPath` at all?

Comment: see http://codepad.org/FyZh0ZMh, modified a bit and it is running fine

Comment: show us the line where you are calling the function

Comment: Nothing does modify the string.

Comment: seems you are working on a big project. My advice would be to debug patiently and check the values of variables at each step. there is something else which we cannot see here

Comment: About initialization order: If both are defined in the same .cpp file, you *can* rely on the initialization order. Only for variables defined in different .cpp files the initialization order is undefined. However it might be that you access `LOG_PATH` before it is properly initialized. From where do you access that? (Anyway, using function-local statics is a good way to avoid initialization order problems.)

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
string str1, str2, strFinal;
strFinal = str1 + "some static string" + str2;
```

Which I think you should

Just for your reference:

```
std::string normalize(std::string parentPath, const std::string& name)
{
    if (name.empty())
        return parentPath;
    else
    {
        if (name[0] != '/')
            parentPath += '/';
        if(name[name.length()-1] != '/')
            parentPath += name;
        else
            parentPath.append(name.begin(), name.end()-1);
        return parentPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between the two (strFinal.append(str1).append(str2) and strFinal = str1 + str2 ?

Comment: Tried it with operator+ instead of append: No concatenation is being done.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the reason of your problem, I strongly suggest you to use this simple version:

```
std::string normalize(std::string parentPath, const std::string& name)
{
    if (name.empty())
        return parentPath;
    else
    {
        if (name.front() != Path::SEGMENT_SEPARATOR)
            parentPath += Path::SEGMENT_SEPARATOR;

        if(name.back() != Path::SEGMENT_SEPARATOR)
            parentPath += name;
        else
            parentPath.append(name.begin(), name.end()-1);

        return parentPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have rewritten the code as suggested (looks a lot cleaner indeed) but there seems to be no difference.

Comment: @Hans: Then your problem probably lies somewhere in the calling code.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an SSCCE demonstrating that your function works correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ce31fd31cb8d5c196dd00ef7f659ee7c-c944ac6b0eed3bfc48b1f78a894f6965). Problem is in code that you are *not* showing us.

Comment: I have added the calling code. The entire Path type is rather large, so I added the constructor definition and the calling code.

Comment: This should really be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly some configuration issue (mismatch in compiler options, linker options or preprocessor defs between the two projects) as it does not occur when the I merge the two projects into one.
Thanks for the comments on the concatenation function: I'll be rewriting it to a more readable form later on.
Thanks to everyone for the helpful comments.

EDIT: found the problem.
A preprocessor #define used to switch on linux dependent implementation of certain members of Path (mainly function creating new dirs and files) was switched on in main project but not in library. This probably caused the problem when the library was linked. Works like a charm now.

Comment: Done. Issue was indeed due to a preprocessor directive not present in the library, where it was used to switch 'on' the linux dependent implementation of certain functions. Because they were present in the executable project it probably broke the linking process. Guess I know now what "undefined behaviour" means :).